# JOOQ Query hierarchy

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

i have a problem with a table call "`menu`". this table save the parent menu item with pid `null` and their child's with `pid` = "parent `id`".

the table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE security.menu (
  id UUID NOT NULL,
  pid UUID DEFAULT NULL,
  url VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50)DEFAULT NULL,
  seq NUMERIC DEFAULT NULL,
  state NUMERIC DEFAULT 1,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And the data is:

[image]

I need build a JOOQ query to retrieve the data in tree mode using the field `seq`, `id` and `pid`.

I need Help to get query result:

```
-Menu 1
     -Sub Menu 1
-Menu 2
-Menu 3
-Menu 1
```

The expected result above takes into account the seq field and the field pid

Comment: Hi there, It's good practice to post what you tried so that people can help you from there. Show some code samples to let community help you better!

Comment: Are your `seq` contents really correct? Why does `Menu 1` and `Menu 2` have the same `seq` value? I'm assuming that `seq` is used to order siblings among any given menu item's children...

Comment: @LukasEder, the `seq` of Menu 2 is wrong, sorry.

Comment: @MG_Bautista: No worries :) Perhaps you should add a `UNIQUE (pid, seq)` key though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Doing it with SQL

For my answer, I'm going to assume that `seq` is being used to order siblings in your menu hierarchy, and that your sample data is wrong (no two siblings may have the same `seq` value, i.e. there should be `UNIQUE (pid, seq)`. So, I'll work with this sample data (`INT` IDs for simplicity):

```sql
INSERT INTO menu (id, pid, name, seq)
VALUES 
  (1, null, 'Menu 1', 1), 
  (2, null, 'Menu 2', 2), 
  (3, null, 'Menu 3', 3), 
  (4, 1, 'Sub Menu 1', 1), 
  (5, null, 'Menu 1', 9);
```

You are going to need a recursive query for that, by using the [`WITH clause`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-clause/). In SQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE m AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    ARRAY[seq] AS path, 
    name, 1 AS level, 
    '- ' || name AS display
  FROM menu
  WHERE pid IS NULL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    menu.id, 
    path || seq, 
    menu.name, 
    m.level + 1 AS level, 
    repeat('  ', m.level) || '- ' || menu.name
  FROM menu JOIN m ON m.id = menu.pid
)
SELECT *
FROM m
ORDER BY path;
```

[The query output can be seen here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/81137/4). It is:

```
id |path  |name       |level |display        |
---|------|-----------|------|---------------|
1  |{1}   |Menu 1     |1     |- Menu 1       |
4  |{1,1} |Sub Menu 1 |2     |  - Sub Menu 1 |
2  |{2}   |Menu 2     |1     |- Menu 2       |
3  |{3}   |Menu 3     |1     |- Menu 3       |
5  |{9}   |Menu 1     |1     |- Menu 1       |
```

There are, of course, other ways to achieve the same result. Column explanations:

- `id`: The original menu item id
- `path`: The path leading to any given menu item (an array of concatenated `seq` value, assuming they are unique per `pid`)
- `name`: The original name of a menu item
- `level`: The recursion or nesting level (useful for padding)
- `display`: The padded display of the menu item, as per your question

#### Doing it with jOOQ

Now, you simply have to translate the above to a jOOQ query.

Assuming these static imports (as always):

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static com.example.generated.Table.*;
```

as follows:

```java
Field<Integer[]> path = array(MENU.SEQ).as("path");
Field<Integer> level = inline(1).as("level");
Field<String> display = inline("- ").concat(MENU.NAME).as("display");

Table<?> m = name("m").as(
  select(MENU.ID, path, MENU.NAME, level, display)
 .from(MENU)
 .where(MENU.PID.isNull())
 .unionAll(
  select(
    MENU.ID,
    PostgresDSL.arrayAppend(path, MENU.SEQ),
    MENU.NAME,
    level.add(inline(1)),
    repeat(inline("  "), level).concat(inline("- ")).concat(MENU.NAME))
 .from(MENU)
 .join(table(name("m"))).on(field(name("m", "id"), Integer.class).eq(MENU.PID)))
);

ctx.selectFrom(m).orderBy(path).fetch();
```