# JOOQ - Recursive Query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have the following database structure:

**File**

- file_id
- file_name
- folder_id

**Folder**

- folder_id
- folder_name
- parent_folder_id

I'm trying to dynamic build the file path this way:

**Query:** - This returns the file and the folder where is located.

```
dsl.select()
   .from( FILE)
   .join( FOLDER)
   .on( FILE.FOLDER_ID.eq( FOLDER.FOLDER_ID) )
   .fetch();
```

And then I get the parent folders in simple Java:

```
List<Folder> parentFolders= new ArrayList<>();
Long parentFolderId = record.get( FOLDER.PARENT_FOLDER_ID );
while ( parentFolderId != null )
{
    Folder parentFolder = folderService.get(parentFolderId );
    parentFolders.add( 0, parentFolder );
    parentFolderId = parentFolder.getParentFolderId();
}
```

Output would look like this for instance:

```
Folder -> Folder -> Folder -> File
```

To maybe be fetched in a class like this:

```
Long fileId;
String fileName;
Long fileId;
String fileName;
List<Folder> parents;
```

Is there any way to do this two steps in JOOQ? The idea is to write a query that does as well the lookup for the parent folders. Is this even possible just with JOOQ?

Comment: 1) Have you tried using [`WITH RECURSIVE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-recursive-clause/)? What did you struggle with? 2) Do you need the `List<Folder> parents` that lists all the parents eagerly or would a simple `Folder parent` reference suffice? (You could still add an auxiliary method that collects the list...)

Comment: A folder parent would suffice I think. I've tried the WITH RECURSIVE but I was only to do a top bottom approach instead of a bottom top because I only want to return the folders that contain files. I've used the example that you pointed but was the problem that I have referenced of being top bottom.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? If yes, it would be nice to answer your own question as I struggle on the same issue and cannot find any doc on jooq for that.

Comment: Maybe this is doing the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550412/jooq-query-hierarchy